# How to fix 'TypeError: this.isCallback is not a function' error for UserAgentApplication in msal.js

Tags: azure-ad-msal

using Msal v1.0.2, loginPopup is not working from iFrame.

trying to get the UserAgentApplication instance using client_id. its throwing an exception:
TypeError: this.isCallback is not a function
    at Object.UserAgentApplication (UserAgentApplication.ts:228)

```
const myMSALObj = Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
myMSALObj.loginPopup(["user.read"]).then(function (loginResponse) {
          return myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest);
        }).then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
          const token = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
        }).catch(function (error) {
          //handle error
        });
```

sample from . 'Quickstart for MSAL JS' works fine but when I try to integrate Msal inside iFrame of my JavaScript plugin code, its not working.

### working code from sample:

```
var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //Please check the console for errors
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a typo causing this exception: TypeError: this.isCallback is not a function at Object.UserAgentApplication (UserAgentApplication.ts:228)

fix: const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

That should solve this exception issue.